# phantomjs create inside express Router does not execute

Tags: node.js, express, phantomjs

I have a server with routes built with `express.Router`. One of the routes uses `phantom.create()` inside. I can't get inside the `create` function, it never executes (or it does but without any effect). I run this script by `node ./path/to/script` :

```
var express = require("express");
var router  = express.Router();

router.post("/my/path", function(req, res) {
  console.log('req.body.myUrl', req.body.myUrl); // this works

  var phantom = require('phantom');
  phantom.create('--debug=true', '--web-security=false', function(ph) {
    // this never happens:
    console.log('phantom');
    return res.status(200).send({ message: "asdasd" });
  });

  console.log('mamma mia') // this works
});
```

The server logs this:

```
req.body.myUrl http://myUrl
mamma mia
# and after a few minutes this:
POST /myUrl - - ms - -
# and then the entire cycle repeats infinitely automatically:
req.body.myUrl http://myUrl
mamma mia
POST /myUrl - - ms - -
```

When I run the same code in a live node session (`$ node`), everything works just fine. Any idea what's the issue here? I've was digging in the `create()` source, but couldn't find any trail there :/

node v6.2.0, express 4.1.0, phantomjs 2.1.1, macOS Sierra 10.12.4,

Answer (score 1):

I've only tested your code with the latest Phantom (4.0.1), so I don't know if it applies to the version you're using, but v4 throws an error regarding the arguments not being passed correctly (they should be passed as an array).

Try this:

```
phantom.create([ '--debug=true', '--web-security=false' ], ...);
```

Comment: Nopes, 2.1.1 wants separate strings.

Comment: Just installed 2.1.1: _"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Unexpected type of parameters. Expecting args to be array."_ Also, does `.create()` actually accept a callback? Does the Phantom-specific code work standalone for you? To be clear: we're talking [about this module](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/tree/v2#phantomcreate), right?

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I am not 100% sure why this didn't work, but there were some environment differences and deep dependencies on extremely obsolete versions (node 0.10 v 5.0, ubuntu v os x, phantom 2 v 3, etc). Even making the env 1:1 didn't solve the problem, perhaps due to imagemagick on ubuntu v on os x(?). I ended up updating all the libs on production & using the same locally, and now all works like a charm :). Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a catch at the end of your create to remove the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.